# Syntax highlighting is pretty outdated for Python code

Tags: feature-request

The syntax highlighter used by Stack Overflow is not rendering some features of Python code correctly.  For example, async / await - not recognized on SO, but that's not a particularly new feature of Python.  The syntax has been around for over 2 years now.

It would be nice to have the most current features like f-strings rendered correctly too (although that's more cutting-edge stuff, so it's understandable if the syntax highlighters may take a few months to catch up).

I know that SO uses [google code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) js for this stuff, so consider this a feature request to update the version of the library in use.  Or, if we are already using a current version, then to consider switching to a different library which keeps up with the times a bit better.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-492-coroutines-with-async-and-await-syntax) is how the code should be highlighted, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46246700/674039) is what it looks like on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You'll have to take that up with the code-prettify project.

Comment: *If it is indeed a bug in the syntax highlighter itself, check the issues list to see if it has already been reported. If it hasn't, feel free to report it or join the project and submit a fix yourself. If you want to ensure that an issue you raised is fixed quickly, it's best to include the fix in the report. If the fix has already been implemented by Prettify but is still not working here, please raise a feature request on Meta to request that a new version of Prettify be deployed.*

Comment: the different library was tried: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please and status-declined.

Comment: What version does SO use?  Is there an online sandbox somewhere to play with the latest version?  I already searched their github issues and pull requests but didn't find anything about async / await python.

Comment: @wim They have a customized version of prettify, which is indicated by the presence of "StackExchange" in the minified form [here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js). It doesn't look like they take PRs for it

Comment: Don't get your hopes up. Prettify doesn't even seem to acknowledge pull requests anymore. Yes, Stack Exchange uses a customized version of Prettify, so even getting your fixes into the upstream Prettify is only half of the battle. You *also* have to persuade the SE devs to update to the latest version.